# How can I combine these two scripts into one in vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am new to VUE. I am trying to modify the old code.
Here is my situation.

In a single component there are two script tags. One of them got something call

`useStore` which imported from `vuex`

Another script got something that got `defineProps` which is grabbing the props passed into the component.

The thing is I got a function which need access to both of them.So I wanna combine the imports but I don't know how to

**Here is the script1**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Spinner from '../common/Spinner.vue';
import Questionnaire from '../Questionnaire/Questionnaire.vue';
import WelcomeScreen from '../common/WelcomeScreen.vue';
import ThankYouScreen from '../common/ThankYouScreen.vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'FullQuestionnaire',
  components: { Spinner, Questionnaire, WelcomeScreen, ThankYouScreen },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
  },
});
</script>
```

**Here is the script2**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { withDefaults, defineProps, computed, ref, toRefs, watch } from 'vue';
import emojiRegex from 'emoji-regex';
import {
  AdditionalParameters,
  QuestionnaireScreen,
  QuestionnaireConfig,
  QuestionnaireStyles,
  RawQuestionnaireStyles,
  QuestionnaireAnswer,
  SubmitAnswersFunction,
} from '../../lib/types';
import { checkAdditions, lightenDarkenColor } from '../../lib/main';

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    isLoading?: boolean;
    additions: AdditionalParameters;
    questionnaireConfig: QuestionnaireConfig;
    questionnaireStyling?: RawQuestionnaireStyles | null;
    submitAnswers: SubmitAnswersFunction;
    goBack: () => void;
  }>(),
  { isLoading: undefined, questionnaireStyling: null }
);


//Function which need access to store from script1 and questionnaireConfig from script 2
  const processedRedirectUrl = computed(() => {
  const url = populatePlaceholdersInLinkQueryParameters(
    redirectUrl.value,
    // **** NEED STORE ACCESS ****
    // store.getters.userProfile
  );
    return url;
});

const finishClickHandler = (): void => {
  props.submitAnswers(questionnaireConfig.value, tAnswers.value, tScore.value);
  if (
    questionnaireConfig.value.thankyou_screens[0] &&
    questionnaireConfig.value.thankyou_screens[0] !== null 
  ) {
    window.location.replace(processedRedirectUrl.value);
  } else {
    console.log("hello")
  }
};

 </script>
```

Comment: Did you try moving the useStore import inside the <script setup> (the 2nd script tag) ??

Answer (score 0):

`<script setup ...>` is a just [syntactic sugar](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html).  There's no need for this component to have both `<script>` and `<script setup>` tags.

It can be defined within a single `<script setup>` like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// The imports from your <script> tag minus defineComponent (not needed)
import Spinner from '../common/Spinner.vue';
import Questionnaire from '../Questionnaire/Questionnaire.vue';
import WelcomeScreen from '../common/WelcomeScreen.vue';
import ThankYouScreen from '../common/ThankYouScreen.vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';


import { withDefaults, defineProps, computed, ref, toRefs, watch } from 'vue';
import emojiRegex from 'emoji-regex';
import {
  AdditionalParameters,
  QuestionnaireScreen,
  QuestionnaireConfig,
  QuestionnaireStyles,
  RawQuestionnaireStyles,
  QuestionnaireAnswer,
  SubmitAnswersFunction,
} from '../../lib/types';
import { checkAdditions, lightenDarkenColor } from '../../lib/main';



// The line in your <scripts> setup() function.
const store = useStore();

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    isLoading?: boolean;
    additions: AdditionalParameters;
    questionnaireConfig: QuestionnaireConfig;
    questionnaireStyling?: RawQuestionnaireStyles | null;
    submitAnswers: SubmitAnswersFunction;
    goBack: () => void;
  }>(),
  { isLoading: undefined, questionnaireStyling: null }
);


//Function which need access to store from script1 and questionnaireConfig from script 2
  const processedRedirectUrl = computed(() => {
  const url = populatePlaceholdersInLinkQueryParameters(
    redirectUrl.value,
    // **** NEED STORE ACCESS ****
    // store.getters.userProfile
  );
    return url;
});

const finishClickHandler = (): void => {
  props.submitAnswers(questionnaireConfig.value, tAnswers.value, tScore.value);
  if (
    questionnaireConfig.value.thankyou_screens[0] &&
    questionnaireConfig.value.thankyou_screens[0] !== null 
  ) {
    window.location.replace(processedRedirectUrl.value);
  } else {
    console.log("hello")
  }
};

 </script>
```